# Storing LoginCredentials in text file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Iam new to java i have a requirement that all the user logged in details are stored in database.The table looks like this

empId  timestamp   empDeparment  empName

1         xxxx         java        xxxx

2         xxxx         testing   xxxxx

I need to get all these list of records and should store in text file based on some conditions.

1.I need to create new folder(directory) for each department for example  "java_currentdate"

2.I need to create a text file the text file look like this

logindetails.txt

1timestamp3(no of employees in java department are 3 so 3 times body repeats)  -----------Header

2empidtimestampempName

2       "                                              -----------body

2       "

3               -----------------footer

All the employees should be sorted based on id and timestamp

Please help me explain to work on this.

I am using hibernate Orm tool and spring

Comment: Have you started on this? Are you stuck somewhere particularly that you're needing some thoughts on?

Comment: I have started this and got all the list of values from db.But stuck up with sorting the employee id and timestamp and storing in a text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too broad.

There are several resources that could be useful:

- Spring Getting Starter guide: [Accessing Relational Data using JDBC with Spring](http://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/)
- Spring Data sample application tutorial: [Spring Data Access Tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/data/)
- Spring Data doc: [Spring Data current](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/)
- JPA Specification
- A lot of examples on the web.

Now, it doesn't matter if you have to write/read on file or DB, as newbie, first of all you have to understand how Spring works to perform data access.